# Monkey Talk - Verify Table Data

Tags: ios, monkeytalk

I'm using Monkey Talk to test an iOS app.  I am creating a user record.  Once created I want to verify the user data.  The user data is displayed in a table on the iOS device as follows:

First Name  Test
Last Name   User 001
EMail       test.user001@gmail.com

I want to verify the data in each of these fields.  I've tried:

Table * Verify Test item(1)

It returns: FAILURE: String "Test" does not match "(null)" or

I'm stumped.  Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are not verifying the table has the value Test, you are verifying a row in the table has that value. If you can, to a component tree view of the page and get the source. Most likely you'll need to verify the cell in a row of the table contains the value you want to verify.